# Does checking for NODE_ENV unnecessarily slow down our Express app in production?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, environment-variables

In an Express app we often check for the environment like so:

```
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

As I see it, this means that even in production every time there is an error the app is checking the environment with:

```
req.app.get('env') === 'development'
```

Am I missing something or is this check completely unnecessary? We could have a build step for Express apps that resolves these checks before deployment. Is this something that PaaS like Heroku already do for us?

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with Node I usually see people reading environment variables with `process.env`. When `process.env.NODE_ENV` is read, Node will perform a system call to read the environment variables from the operating system (`NODE_ENV` in this case). This is a somewhat expensive operation and could cause performance issues in a hotspot. A solution would be to cache the value, so that the code reads the value directly from a local variable instead of the OS.

However, you seem to be using a cached value already. If we look at the [Express source code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090ca91f6a387e66370d57ead94d886275e1/lib/application.js#L71), we can see that it assigns `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `env`, which is what you are reading with `req.app.get('env')`. From what I can tell you are therefore doing a read that is free for all practical purposes. I wouldn't worry about making Heroku hardcode it, which is probably not possible out-of-the-box anyway.